# What is the meaning of the sentence "Hopes dashed through" and what is the use of Through" as an adverb?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, prepositional-phrases, poetry

I'm reading E.A.Poe Complete tales and Poems and I found out this interesting phrase In which a have a question.

> ... was caracterized by a dramatic stories, Breakdowns and
>   recoveries, personal gains and ***hopes dashed through***".

I see that the meaning of the last part Is that Poe had a lot of hopes that he had to throw away. Is that correct? Is there a phrasal verb or an idiom that I may check to understand this sentence a slightly better?

Thanks!

Comment: It could give the meaning of "completion" too, his hopes may have been meet or not, it goes with how you interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary.com gives a definition of dash (v.) as "6. to ruin or frustrate (hopes, plans, etc.)" and dash (n.) as "13. the mark or sign (—) used to note an abrupt break or pause in a sentence or hesitation in an utterance, to begin and end a parenthetic word, phrase, or clause, to indicate the omission of letters or words, to divide a line, to substitute for certain uses of the colon, and to separate any of various elements of a sentence or series of sentences, as a question from its answer." (basically the "-" sign).

I think the "through" refers to drawing a line through, or crossing out; in other words, to have his hopes dashed through means they were crossed out, i.e. compelled to be given up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that *through*, in this case, describes the completeness with which his hopes were dashed. "Hopes dashed" is already an English expression in various formulations meaning the failure of a person's plans to work out as desired.

If you remove *through* from the sentence, it still carries the same meaning (the hopes were ruined and were therefore no longer operative), and the A:B organization of the sentence suggests that that phrase should indicate a negative event (to balance the *personal gains* and maintain the rhetorical structure being used).

Similarly, an object could be cut or cut through. The latter indicates that the cut completely divided the object. The former could also describe that same degree of cutting, but doesn't necessarily.